# Windows API USB IO (winusb.dll)

Tags: c#, winapi, usb, hid, winusb

**Edit: This question evolved over time. The basic question was about how to connect to a and read/write to/from a USB device in Windows. Eventually I answered the question with the help of @benvoigt.**

I have written a Hid library which writes and reads to/from Hid USB devices. It works well. However, the device I am connecting to has switched from Hid access to vanilla USB. The Hid code does not work when connecting to the different type of device. My aim now is to connect to the USB interface (as opposed to the Hid interface) and read/write to/from it.

On all platforms that access USB, we have to query the interfaces that exist for the USB device, and then "claim" an interface for reading and writing. Here is some code from a LibUsbDotNet sample (LibUsb is a working C USB library and LibUsbDotNet wraps it) https://github.com/LibUsbDotNet/LibUsbDotNet/blob/master/src/Examples/Read.Write/ReadWrite.cs.

```
            using (var context = new UsbContext())
            {
                context.SetDebugLevel(LogLevel.Info);

                //Get a list of all connected devices
                var usbDeviceCollection = context.List();

                //Narrow down the device by vendor and pid
                var selectedDevice = usbDeviceCollection.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ProductId == ProductId && d.VendorId == VendorId);

                //Open the device
                selectedDevice.Open();

                //Get the first config number of the interface
                selectedDevice.ClaimInterface(selectedDevice.Configs[0].Interfaces[0].Number);

                //Open up the endpoints
                var writeEndpoint = selectedDevice.OpenEndpointWriter(WriteEndpointID.Ep01);
                var readEnpoint = selectedDevice.OpenEndpointReader(ReadEndpointID.Ep01);

                //Create a buffer with some data in it
                var buffer = new byte[64];
                buffer[0] = 0x3f;
                buffer[1] = 0x23;
                buffer[2] = 0x23;

                //Write three bytes
                writeEndpoint.Write(buffer, 3000, out var bytesWritten);

                var readBuffer = new byte[64];

                //Read some data
                readEnpoint.Read(readBuffer, 3000, out var readBytes);
            }
}
```

I have a feeling that LibUsb is achieving the opening of interfaces/endpoints in C like this (https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/c6f3866414e8deeee19e8a9f10f20bde9cb408d3/libusb/os/windows_winusb.c#L2199) . This is where it calls Initialize: https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/c6f3866414e8deeee19e8a9f10f20bde9cb408d3/libusb/os/windows_winusb.c#L2225 which is where my code is failing.

A little snippet of information is that this is definitely a WinUSB device. I can see that here:

[image]

Based on other people's comments and sample code, I can see that I need to use winusb.dll. I am able to call CreateFile to get a handle from the device. According to other sample code I have seen, the next step is to call WinUsb_Initialize. However, when I call this, I get an error code of 8 (ERROR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY). There is some information here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winusb/nf-winusb-winusb_initialize . But, I don't quite understand what it is asking me to do. This is my code so far:

```
    public override async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        Dispose();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeviceId))
        {
            throw new WindowsException($"{nameof(DeviceDefinition)} must be specified before {nameof(InitializeAsync)} can be called.");
        }

        _DeviceHandle = APICalls.CreateFile(DeviceId, (APICalls.GenericWrite | APICalls.GenericRead), APICalls.FileShareRead | APICalls.FileShareWrite, IntPtr.Zero, APICalls.OpenExisting, APICalls.FileAttributeNormal | APICalls.FileFlagOverlapped, IntPtr.Zero);

        var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (errorCode > 0) throw new Exception($"Write handle no good. Error code: {errorCode}");

        if (_DeviceHandle.IsInvalid) throw new Exception("Device handle no good");

        var isSuccess = WinUsbApiCalls.WinUsb_Initialize(_DeviceHandle, out var interfaceHandle);

        errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

        if (!isSuccess) throw new Exception($"Initialization failed. Error code: {errorCode}");

        IsInitialized = true;

        RaiseConnected();
    }
```

You can clone the branch of this repo here: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/tree/WindowsUsbDevice. Just run the Usb.Net.WindowsSample project.

I also tried this and got exactly the same result:

```
public override async Task InitializeAsync()
{
    Dispose();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DeviceId))
    {
        throw new WindowsException($"{nameof(DeviceDefinition)} must be specified before {nameof(InitializeAsync)} can be called.");
    }

    _DeviceHandle = APICalls.CreateFile(DeviceId, (APICalls.GenericWrite | APICalls.GenericRead), APICalls.FileShareRead | APICalls.FileShareWrite, IntPtr.Zero, APICalls.OpenExisting, APICalls.FileAttributeNormal | APICalls.FileFlagOverlapped, IntPtr.Zero);

    var errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    if (errorCode > 0) throw new Exception($"Write handle no good. Error code: {errorCode}");

    var interfaceHandle = new IntPtr();

    var pDll = NativeMethods.LoadLibrary(@"C:\GitRepos\Device.Net\src\Usb.Net.WindowsSample\bin\Debug\net452\winusb.dll");

    var pAddressOfFunctionToCall = NativeMethods.GetProcAddress(pDll, "WinUsb_Initialize");

    var initialize = (WinUsb_Initialize)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall, typeof(WinUsb_Initialize));

    var isSuccess = initialize(_DeviceHandle, ref interfaceHandle);

    errorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    if (!isSuccess) throw new Exception($"Initialization failed. Error code: {errorCode}");

    IsInitialized = true;

    RaiseConnected();
}

[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
private delegate bool WinUsb_Initialize(SafeFileHandle DeviceHandle, ref IntPtr InterfaceHandle);
```

I strongly believe that there is something wrong with the device's WinUSB implementation itself. It works with other libraries like LibUsb, UWP, and Android, but WinUsb doesn't seem to like it. I tried this library: https://github.com/madwizard-thomas/winusbnet and it also fails on the same call with the same error code. The line it fails on and gets error code 8 is here: https://github.com/madwizard-thomas/winusbnet/blob/8f62d751a99be1e31d34b91115715d60aeff2dfc/WinUSBNet/API/WinUSBDevice.cs#L225

**What is wrong with my code here? Is there something I need to do to allocate memory for the WinUsb_Initialize call?**

**How should I use the winusb.dll Windows API? What API calls do I need to make to claim and interface or endpoint for reading and writing?**

**It would really help me if someone could point me to a simple C or C# sample that reads and writes to a USB device and actually works**.

WinDBG output:

> ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location Deferred
>   srv* Symbol search path is: srv* Executable search path is:  ModLoad:
>   00000236`157c0000 00000236`157c8000   Usb.Net.WindowsSample.exe
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`62880000 00007ffb`62a61000   ntdll.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`60f40000 00007ffb`610d0000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\user32.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`5ed00000 00007ffb`5ed20000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`4e1b0000
>   00007ffb`4e214000   C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSCOREE.DLL ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`612a0000 00007ffb`612c8000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
>   onecore\windows\core\console\open\src\renderer\gdi\invalidate.cpp(121)\conhost.exe!00007FF7169FE2AF:
>   (caller: 00007FF7169FF414) ReturnHr(1) tid(4230) 80070578 Invalid
>   window handle. ModLoad: 00007ffb`60990000 00007ffb`60a42000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`5f000000
>   00007ffb`5f192000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`60d90000 00007ffb`60f03000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`5ed80000 00007ffb`5eff3000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`60610000
>   00007ffb`606d2000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`60f10000 00007ffb`60f3d000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
>
> ************* Path validation summary ************** Response                         Time (ms)     Location Deferred
>   srv* Symbol search path is: srv* Executable search path is:  ModLoad:
>   00007ff7`169f0000 00007ff7`16a8f000   conhost.exe ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`61340000 00007ffb`62780000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shell32.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`5cd80000 00007ffb`5cda9000
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\dwmapi.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`62880000
>   00007ffb`62a61000   ntdll.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`5fcc0000
>   00007ffb`5fd09000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`5f530000 00007ffb`5fc3d000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
>   onecore\windows\core\console\open\src\renderer\gdi\invalidate.cpp(121)\conhost.exe!00007FF7169FE2AF:
>   (caller: 00007FF7169FF414) ReturnHr(2) tid(4230) 80070578 Invalid
>   window handle. ModLoad: 00007ffb`61140000 00007ffb`61191000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shlwapi.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`60990000
>   00007ffb`60a42000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`5ec30000 00007ffb`5ec41000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`5ed80000
>   00007ffb`5eff3000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`5ec10000 00007ffb`5ec2f000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`5ebc0000 00007ffb`5ec0c000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`5ebb0000
>   00007ffb`5ebba000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\FLTLIB.DLL ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`5f490000 00007ffb`5f52f000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`5f1a0000
>   00007ffb`5f29a000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`606e0000 00007ffb`60789000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`4e290000 00007ffb`4e4f9000
>   C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.17134.472_none_fb3f9af53068156d\comctl32.DLL
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`5ca60000 00007ffb`5caf8000
>   C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`608f0000
>   00007ffb`6098e000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`601e0000 00007ffb`60304000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`60a60000 00007ffb`60d82000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`5fc40000
>   00007ffb`5fcba000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll ModLoad:
>   00007ffb`627a0000 00007ffb`62841000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\advapi32.dll
>   ModLoad: 00007ffb`610d0000 00007ffb`6112b000
>   C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll ModLoad: 00007ffb`57b30000
>   00007ffb`57bc6000   C:\WINDOWS\System32\TextInputFramework.dll
>   (3d80.256c): Break instruction exception - code 80000003 (first
>   chance) ntdll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak+0x30: 00007ffb`6294c93c cc
>   int     3

Comment: How are you ensuring that your access is aligned and uses exact multiples of sector size. Why isn't there a [mcve]?

Comment: I think the answer to that question is that I have tried all the sector sizes (data buffer sizes) I know of and they all yield the same result. Part of the problem is that the size that the device expects is 64 bytes, and yet if I specify 64, I get an error. I have to send 64, but specify 65. There is some kind of issue with Windows IO. To answer your second question, unless you have a Trezor hardwarewallet, there is no way to verify the example. My question is a general one - not a specific one:  "Any advice on the differences between talking to a vanilla USB device vs. a Hid device?"

Comment: General questions are not a fit here. "Does anyone have any general advice" is not a suitable question. As far as alignment and buffer size goes, you can't know what is used because you have delegated it to the stream which may do its own buffering. Use ReadFile directly. Far easier in C++. At least whilst debugging and learning.

Comment: Why should I use ReadFile directly? I have tried it, and it didn't work, but why is this better?

Comment: Because then you control the alignment and buffer size. You will also receive Win32 error messages. It would be so much easier for you to test this out with C++ code. There are so many extra ways for things to go wrong using C#. Do the device vendors have any sample code?

Comment: When I tried calling WriteFile, I got the error 1, and 6. I have written code for it on three platforms: Android, UWP, and Windows. It's been working well, but writing to Hid is evidently different to writing to USB. My question is, what am I supposed to do differently when talking to a normal USB device as opposed to Hid?

Comment: This is how I control the buffer size: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Hid.Net/blob/03a00f368ba67157ea655f5b16d3714f31e9564f/Hid.Net/Windows/WindowsDeviceBase.cs#L150 . It is always 64 in and out. I've tested that thoroughly and know that it works.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have cleaned up this question. Basically, I need to know which API calls to make in order to claim a USB interface/endpoint for reading/writing to a USB device. Whether the answer is in C or C# doesn't matter. I just need to know what the API calls are.

Comment: `InterfaceHandle` should be `out`, not `ref`, but that shouldn't change much your issue. Beyond that the declaration looks fine. I can't reproduce the error 8. When I tried to open devices on my PC, I only get error 50 (ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED). Maybe the issue is with this specific USB 'trezor' device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to connect to and read/write to/from a USB device via the WinUSB library

All this code is contained in the Device.Net repo: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net . There is a sample here. It automatically switched between Hid, and UWP depending on which device is plugged in. https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/master/src/Usb.Net.WindowsSample/Program.cs

**Connect and get Information**

- Call SetupDiGetClassDevs to enumerate devices with the WinUSB Guid (dee824ef-729b-4a0e-9c14-b7117d33a817). Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Device.Net/Windows/WindowsDeviceFactoryBase.cs#L35
- Call SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail to get details about the interface and filter by Vid/Pid. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Device.Net/Windows/WindowsDeviceFactoryBase.cs#L64
- Call CreateFile with the returned Device Path. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L44
- Call WinUsb_Initialize with the handle you got from the previous call. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L53
- Call WinUsb_GetDescriptor to get information about the device. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L57
- Call WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings to get information about the interfaces belonging to the USB device. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L141
- Call WinUsb_QueryPipe for each pipe that belongs to the interface. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L148
- Call WinUsb_GetAssociatedInterface to get other interfaces other than the default. This will probably not be necessary because you will already have the default interface handle from WinUsb_Initialize. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L69

**Write and Read**

- Call WinUsb_WritePipe to write an array of data. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L115
- Call WinUsb_ReadPipe to read an array of data. Code: https://github.com/MelbourneDeveloper/Device.Net/blob/58aca0de118576ba89ec7437b29176d9bdd90aea/src/Usb.Net/Windows/WindowsUsbDevice.cs#L98

**API Calls**

```
public static class Kernel32APICalls
{
    //Abridged

    #region Kernel32
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess, uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition, uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);
    #endregion    
}

public static partial class WinUsbApiCalls
{
    public const uint DEVICE_SPEED = 1;
    public const byte USB_ENDPOINT_DIRECTION_MASK = 0X80;
    public const int WritePipeId = 0x80;

    /// <summary>
    /// Not sure where this constant is defined...
    /// </summary>
    public const int DEFAULT_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE = 0x01;

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_ControlTransfer(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, WINUSB_SETUP_PACKET SetupPacket, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, ref uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_GetAssociatedInterface(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte AssociatedInterfaceIndex, out SafeFileHandle AssociatedInterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_GetDescriptor(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte DescriptorType, byte Index, ushort LanguageID, out USB_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR deviceDesc, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransfered);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_Free(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_Initialize(SafeFileHandle DeviceHandle, out SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_QueryDeviceInformation(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, uint InformationType, ref uint BufferLength, ref byte Buffer);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_QueryInterfaceSettings(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte AlternateInterfaceNumber, out USB_INTERFACE_DESCRIPTOR UsbAltInterfaceDescriptor);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_QueryPipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte AlternateInterfaceNumber, byte PipeIndex, out WINUSB_PIPE_INFORMATION PipeInformation);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_ReadPipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_SetPipePolicy(IntPtr InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, uint PolicyType, uint ValueLength, ref uint Value);

    [DllImport("winusb.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool WinUsb_WritePipe(SafeFileHandle InterfaceHandle, byte PipeID, byte[] Buffer, uint BufferLength, out uint LengthTransferred, IntPtr Overlapped);
}
```

Special thanks to @benvoigt for keeping me moving on this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the weirdness you are seeing around 64 byte transfers is well known:

> ## Delimiting write transfers with short packets
>
> The USB driver stack
>   driver does not impose the same restrictions on packet size, when
>   writing to the device, that it imposes when reading from the device.
>   Some client drivers must make frequent transmissions of small
>   quantities of control data to manage their devices. It is impractical
>   to restrict data transmissions to packets of uniform size in such
>   cases. Therefore, the driver stack does not assign any special
>   significance to packets of size less than the endpoint's maximum size
>   during data writes. This allows a client driver to break a large
>   transfer to the device into multiple URBs of any size less than or
>   equal to the maximum.
>
> The driver must either end the transmission by means of a packet of
>   less than maximum size, or delimit the end of the transmission by
>   means of a zero-length packet. The transmission is not complete until
>   the driver sends a packet smaller than wMaxPacketSize. **If the transfer
>   size is an exact multiple of the maximum, the driver must send a
>   zero-length delimiting packet to explicitly terminate the transfer**
>
> Delimiting the data transmission with zero-length packets, as required
>   by the USB specification, is the responsibility of the client driver.
>   The USB driver stack does not generate these packets automatically.

From [USB Transfer and Packet Sizes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ff538112) on MSDN

---

As for the rest... depending on whether the device declares itself to be a composite device or not, Windows's driver loader will pick either one or multiple device drivers to connect to the device.  Those drivers handle choosing which endpoint on the device to talk to.  So from userspace, it is normally enough to open the driver interface and begin doing I/O.  The HID class driver, for example, knows how to identify and enable the HID endpoint.

Since you have things working with UWP, it seems likely that you have the WinUSB driver loaded (since that's [Step #1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/talking-to-usb-devices-start-to-finish#step1)).  Therefore you'll use the WinUSB API to talk to it.

Here's the documentation for [the C and C++ API for WinUSB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/using-winusb-api-to-communicate-with-a-usb-device).  It has examples of endpoint setup, and looks quite a bit less messy than the libusb code you quoted (although that may have to do with code formatting and style as well).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185859/discussion-on-answer-by-ben-voigt-windows-api-usb-io-winusb-dll).